# How to get menu item that is associated with a switchcompat (Compound Button) inside onCheckedChanged()?

Tags: android

I have a dynamically created a menu item for a navigation view bar and associated it with a switchcompat widget. I want to bind the switch button to the menu item so that clicking on the switch will invoke the same method as the menu item click which presently is not happening for me. Can this be done, if yes, how?

Many Thanks in advance.

```
final MenuItem scanMenuItem = navMenu.getItem(parentMenuItem)
                         .getSubMenu().add(childMenuItem,itemId,orderId,menuTitle)
                         .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_cast)
                         .setActionView(R.layout.compat_switch_button);
...
...

compatSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(MainActivity.this);

...
...
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

   ?? How can I get menuItem the switch button is associated with in this block??

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getId() function inside onCheckedChanged() method

```
if(buttonView.getId()==R.id.menuid)
{
//do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work as my menu items are dynamically added.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know if this is the best approach to solving the problem, I got it working by using a methods called setTag() & getTag() of switchCompat.

```
    compactSwitch.setTag(item.getItemId()); --> the menu item id.
    compactSwitch..setOnCheckedChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
    ...

     @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    int viewId = buttonView.getId();

    switch(viewId){
        case R.id.switch_compat:
    final int anInt = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString()); --> fetch the menuItem Id.
        break;
    }
}
```